# Can I cut a 4x4 stud to frame a pet door without carrying load?

Tags: framing, load-bearing, pet-door

[image][image][image]I want to frame in a pet door in an exterior wall, next to the man door in my garage. Cut a small section to see what I was up against and found a 4x4. Can I safely cut this to install a header/jack studs without carrying the load? Id rather not tear out the dry wall all the way up.

Thanks![image]

Comment: 4x4s are rarely used in residential framing. Is it instead a flat 2x4? Without more context it's difficult to say.

Comment: I guess there's no room to install the door a little to the left or right?

Comment: It is a full 4x4. Dog door is 15x20 so unfortunatly not

Comment: You've verified that it's a 4x4, but you haven't expanded our view. We have no idea why that post is there. What's on the other side of the wall? What's above it?

Comment: Updated with pics of both sides